# Spring @Value always results to `null`

Tags: java, spring

I'm trying to figure out why my Spring @Value always results to `null`:

```
@Value("#{${some.global.property: {'foo':'bar'}}}")
private Map<String, String> myMap; //myMap always results to null
```

I mean, it could be that my global property isn't stored in the right place, but then shouldn't it result to the default value (`{'foo':'bar'}`) in this case?

Here is how I'm trying to use this in a context of a service class:

```java
import java.util.*;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class MyService {
    @Value("#{${some.global.property: {'foo':'bar'}}}")
    private Map<String, String> myMap; //myMap always results to null

    @Autowired
    public MyService(
            // other class services..
    ) {
        // init members...
    }

    private Map<String, String> demoMethod() {
        return this.myMap; //always return null
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: have you ever seen any code in which you can actually 'fetch' a Map filled with data from a properties file like this?

Comment: The most common reason why a `@Value` or `@Autowired` field is `null` in a Spring application is because you're not using the class as a Spring bean. How are you using `MyService` exactly? Are you getting it from the Spring application context, or are you instantiating it with `new` yourself (in which case your `@Value` field will be `null`)?

Comment: @Stultuske - yes, [check this out](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-value-annotation#using-value-with-maps)

Comment: could you show your properties? do your other autowires/value annotations work?

Comment: @Jesper - this service is part of an existing Spring application. The service was in use before I was trying to add to use this value in and is auto-wired to other services  provided by the app.

Comment: @Stultuske - other autowires work. This is the only value I'm currently using. As for my properties, they are located in an env file - but even if it's not set up properly, shouldn't I get the default value?

Comment: Did you try `@Value("#{${some.global.property}: {'foo':'bar'}}")` or  `@Value("#{${some.global.property: {foo:'bar'}}}")`?

Comment: @itaydafna null is the default value for any object

Comment: @Stultuske - that's right, but I'm trying to explicitly declare a different default value by doing this: `: {'foo':'bar'}`

Comment: @itaydafna I just tried the same property and same `@Value` you have in the example and it worked like a charm (even the default value). Stupid question, but are you sure the value it is not been overwritten or property / env var setting this property to null? And your service it is been @Autowired properly with the caller of it? Unless Spring inject your service, it is not gonna work.
Here is a full example with this property default working: https://gist.github.com/BHRother/230faa39fe67814081e334c3ea125390

Comment: @itaydafna according to the example you point to: {key1: '1', key2: '2'} it should be {foo:'bar'}, not {'foo':'bar'}

Comment: @Brother - thanks for your detailed comment - I think it might have led me to realizing what's wrong. It might be that my service is also instantiated and ran by a unit-test which isn't auto-wired by Spring - and this is where I'm getting the `null` value.  Looking into it..

Comment: @itaydafna That's what I thought, your example it is perfectly functional, so it had to be the way your service it's been initialised/injected. If you need extra help, update the question with the part creating/calling the service. Otherwise I would add this as part of the answer so you can accept as it helped and it helps me as well =)

Answer (score 2):

If you have the right property value set in properties file and your bean creation and injection is correct, then it should work fine.

A working example:

```java
// in properties file:

some.global.property={foo:'bar'}
```

```java
@Service
public class MyService {
    @Value("#{${some.global.property}}")
    private Map<String, String> myMap;

    public Map<String, String> getMyMap() {
        return myMap;
    }
}
```

```java
In another service for example:

@Autowired
MyService myService;

public void testService() {
    System.out.println(myService.getMyMap());
    // prints {foo=bar}
}
```